# How do you promote your papers in Mendeley?

Tags: publications, citations, software, website

A colleague of mine says mendeley is a good place for promoting published papers to be read by peers. However, as I tried, it is a private library for a person or a group of people.

Am I missing something? Is there an option to promote your uploaded papers publicly?

Answer (score 5):

Mendeley has two types of groups- Public and Private According to their [website](https://www.mendeley.com/research-network/groups)

> Create and join Public Groups to share knowledge and discuss new
>   research with others with similar interests. You can also create
>   Private Groups that are only visible to invited members, letting you
>   share information securely.

When discussing [setting up a profile](https://www.mendeley.com/guides/web/04-complete-profile) it promotes the idea of you been able to publize your publications through mendeley.

> Publications - Adding your publications to your profile allows you to
>   publicize your work to a global audience. You can add your
>   publications to the My Publications folder in Mendeley Desktop or Web
>   Library, or upload them directly via your profile. You can also add
>   the entire contents of your Scopus Author Profile in one batch

On [another page](https://www.mendeley.com/guides/web/06-stats) it states that you can promote your work publicly

> By connecting your Mendeley profile to your Scopus Author Profile, you
>   are able to claim your work as identified by Scopus. This allows you
>   to publicly promote your authored work, and access a wealth of data
>   provided by Scopus - as well as several other Elsevier services - in
>   the form of Stats.

For your publications to be seen publicly you probably would have to edit your privacy settings and select for you publications to be seen by everyone. [Picture source](https://www.mendeley.com/guides/web/04-grow-your-research-network)[image]